# The Active Tool Tab in the Properites Editor is Entirely Empty

Tags: interface, sculpting, properties, tools

I was doing some sculpting and went to change some of the settings on the tool I was using, but the *Active Tool* tab was entirely empty. [image: An Image displaying Blender, the 3D viewport is in Sculpt mode and the Properties Panel is set to Active Tool, but is entirely empty]

I don't know what could have caused this and I couldn't find any way to fix it nor find anything about this online.

What could have caused this and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: it looks like a bug no? Maybe append your object in a brand new file?

Comment: Broken add-on that adds something to the tab, could do that. I would try temporarily disabling related add-ons and restarting Blender to see if that's the case.